# Add/Substract based on value in cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to do a Point Buy Calculator for DnD.

The code is skipping 13 and 15.

C11 is the ability score that starts at 8. G10 is how much points you have left to spend on the said score.

```
Private Sub CONpointInc_SpinDown()

    If Range("G10").Value <> 0 Then

        If Range("c11").Value <> 8 Then

            Range("c11").Value = Range("c11").Value - 1
            Range("G10").Value = Range("G10").Value + 1

            If Range("c11").Value > 14 Then
                Range("c11").Value = Range("c11").Value - 1
                Range("G10").Value = Range("G10").Value + 2
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub CONpointInc_SpinUp()

If Range("G10").Value <> 28 Then

    If Range("c11").Value <> 15 Then

        Range("c11").Value = Range("c11").Value + 1
        Range("G10").Value = Range("G10").Value - 1

        If Range("c11").Value > 13 Then
            Range("c11").Value = Range("c11").Value + 1
            Range("G10").Value = Range("G10").Value - 2

        End If
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

When the ability score, or C11, is between 8 and 13, it should deduct/add 1 to G10, which is how much points you have left to add.

When C11 is 14 and 15 it should deduct/add 2 to G10.

It should not work when it goes below 8 (which it does) and when it passes 15 (which it does not because it skips 15).

Comment: "What this code should ideally do is when the ability score, or C11, is between 8 and 13, it should [...]" `If Range("C11") > 8 And Range("C11") < 13 Then [...]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this will help:

```
Private Sub CONpointInc_SpinDown()
    If Range("G10").Value <> 0 Then
        If Range("c11").Value > 8 Then
            If Range("c11").Value <= 13 Then
                Range("c11").Value = Range("c11").Value - 1
                Range("G10").Value = Range("G10").Value + 1
            ElseIf Range("C11").Value <= 15 Then
                Range("c11").Value = Range("c11").Value - 1
                Range("G10").Value = Range("G10").Value + 2
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub CONpointInc_SpinUp()
    If Range("G10").Value <> 28 Then
        If Range("c11").Value >= 8 Then
            If Range("c11").Value < 13 Then
                Range("c11").Value = Range("c11").Value + 1
                Range("G10").Value = Range("G10").Value - 1
            ElseIf Range("c11").Value < 15 Then
                Range("c11").Value = Range("c11").Value + 1
                Range("G10").Value = Range("G10").Value - 2
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

P.S. Happy DnD sessions :)